# inserting selected option from dropdown into db codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been working on a registration form which has a dropdown list populated from an associative array like this:

```
        **<?php
        **$options = array(
            'cbaringo'    => 'Baringo',
            'cbomet'    => 'Bomet',
            'cbungoma'    => 'Bungoma',
            'cbusia'    => 'Busia',
            'celgeyo'    => 'Elgeyo Marakwet',
            'cmigori'    => 'Migori',**
        ?>**
```

I want to insert the option the user selects into a database as follows

```
 **$data = array(
            'scounty' => $this->input->post('counties'),
            'ssubcounty' => $this->input->post('subcounty'),
            'sname' => $this->input->post('dschoolname'),
            'skcpecode' => $this->input->post('dkcpecode'),
            'stelno' => $this->input->post('dtelno'),
            'steampatronname' => $this->input->post('dpatroname'),
            'steampatronemail' => $this->input->post('dpatronemail'),
            'steampatrontelno' => $this->input->post('dpatrontelno'),
            's_password' => $this->input->post('scpassword')
        );**
```

pupulated the dropdown like this:

```
**echo form_dropdown('counties', $options, 'cdefault');**
```

The above line displays the options on the dropdown list as expected

```
        //inserted data into db
        **$this->my_model->insert_data($data);**
```

however on inserting the key instead of value from the associative array is inserted into db. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

what you see in a select list is different then the value that is passed from it

```
$options = 
           // the value    // what the user sees in the drop down
array(
            'cbaringo'    => 'Baringo',
            'cbomet'    => 'Bomet',
            'cbungoma'    => 'Bungoma',
            'cbusia'    => 'Busia',
            'celgeyo'    => 'Elgeyo Marakwet',
            'cmigori'    => 'Migori',**
        ?>
```

so if they choose Baringo, the value passed should be cbaringo

Comment: so what should i do to get the value not the key?

Comment: Change your array. Change cbarningo to Baringo or whatever it is you need. If you view source on the web page and look at the html code in the select list this is going to be much clearer.

Comment: i solved it by using option tag within a select tag. Thank you for the hints